# why there is an runtime error in this instruction

Tags: android

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.openOrCreateDatabase("students", MODE_PRIVATE, null);

/* db.execSQL("create table info (" +
    "id integer PRIMARY KEY autoincrement," +
    "name text);" );*/

//   db.execSQL("insert into info (name) values ('Ahmed');");

//   db.execSQL("insert into info (name) values ('Ali');");

Toast.makeText(this, "databse done and informations inserted succesfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Cursor c1 = db.rawQuery("select * from info where name = 'ahmed';", null);

//this line gives runtime error
String x = c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("name"));

Toast.makeText(this, x, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: its only show a message contain " force to close application "

Comment: when i comment each line i conclude that this line is caused the exception String x = c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("name")); but i dont know why

Comment: do you have logcat installed?

Comment: If you are using the command-line, run `adb logcat` and post the exception message it shows. Eclipse has a similar command somewhere, but I'm not as familiar with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `c1.moveToFirst();` before the line

```
String x = c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("name"));
```

Also, consider using `getColumnIndexOrThrow` instead of `getColumnIndex` to make sure that you specified the right column name (otherwise you will get an exception)

In general, it is better to use `query` instead of `rawQuery` especially in your example where you do a simple query

Comment: thats work , thanks alot , byt why I must add .moveToFirst() ?!?